# python Search for text in a gtk textview

Tags: python, search, text, gtk, textview

I have looked around and I would think this to be really simple, for some reason I ahve only found parts of what I need.

I have made a text editor and I have a box that what is typed it will find the problem is that it will only find the first word the in the text view adn I can't get it to search the next line.
like a find function in a textdocument.

```
def search(found):
    search_str = findentry.get_text()
    start_iter =  textbuffer.get_start_iter()
    found =       start_iter.forward_search(search_str,0, None) 
    if found:
      match_start,match_end = found
      textbuffer.select_range(match_start,match_end)
```

I thought I would be able to do a button that is a search next and make it forward search again adding something and a variable +1.
how can I make it search forward and backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get_start_iter()`, which returns the first position in text buffer.  Probably, you want to start from `match_end`, which is the position where word ends in the first search, that is, you should start from there.

Assuming you are returning `found` and calling again `search` with that parameter, then can replace the line:

```
    start_iter =  textbuffer.get_start_iter()
```

by

```
    start_iter = found[1] if found else textbuffer.get_start_iter()
```

The first time, or whenever you want to reset the search, you can pass `found=None`.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. your instructions seem simple enough but could you give a more verbose example please.